# how get the QWidget from a not current tab in QtabBar in PyQt

Tags: python, python-2.7, qt, pyqt, pyqt4

lets say that i know/have the tabIndex from the tab below the cursor in the QTabBar, how could i get the widget inside of X tab in my tabBar? i dont Want the CurrentWidget(), because thats to easy, i want to get the widget of every tab that i want, in order to insert the right one into another QTabWidget when i drop it.

```
class ColtTab(qg.QTabWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ColtTab,self).__init__()

        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.tabBar = self.tabBar()
        self.tabBar.setMouseTracking(True)
        #self.tabBar.installEventFilter(self)
        self.setDocumentMode(True)
        self.indexTab = None

    # Events
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, e):
        if e.buttons() != qc.Qt.MiddleButton:
            return

        globalPos = self.mapToGlobal(e.pos())
        print(globalPos) 
        tabBar = self.tabBar
        print(tabBar)
        posInTab = tabBar.mapFromGlobal(globalPos)
        print(posInTab)        
        self.indexTab = tabBar.tabAt(e.pos())
        print(self.indexTab)
        tabRect = tabBar.tabRect(self.indexTab)
        print(tabRect)
        print(tabRect.size())        

        pixmap = qg.QPixmap(tabRect.size())
        tabBar.render(pixmap,qc.QPoint(),qg.QRegion(tabRect))
        mimeData = qc.QMimeData()
        drag = qg.QDrag(tabBar)
        drag.setMimeData(mimeData)
        drag.setPixmap(pixmap)
        cursor = qg.QCursor(qc.Qt.OpenHandCursor)    
        drag.setHotSpot(e.pos() - posInTab)
        drag.setDragCursor(cursor.pixmap(),qc.Qt.MoveAction)

        dropAction = drag.exec_(qc.Qt.MoveAction)


    def mousePressEvent(self, e):
        #super().mousePressEvent(e)
        if e.button() == qc.Qt.RightButton:
            print('press')


    def dragEnterEvent(self, e):
        e.accept()


    def dropEvent(self, e):
        e.setDropAction(qc.Qt.MoveAction)
        e.accept()

        self.insertTab(self.indexTab,self.currentWidget(), self.tabText(self.indexTab)) 

        # HERE IN THE DROP EVENT I NEED TO INSERT THE CORRECT TAB INTO ANOTHER TABWIDGET, BUT I CAN ONLY INSERT THE CURRENT
```

Comment: [QTabWidget.widget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtabwidget.html#widget).

Comment: i dont know why i tryed many times and didnt work, so dumb me, thank you @ekhumoro